# turn off my laptop with the power button and the system won't boot

Tags: 20.04

the system was working without problems but I turned it off with the laptop button and now starting the system is stuck for more than 15 minutes on a flickering screen with this error

/dev/sda5: clean, xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx files, xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx blocks

Comment: I would avoid using the power-button to turn your system off, it's an unclean shutdown. You can also use SysRq commands to bypass any stuck GUI/UI issue allowing you to directly command the kernel to cleanly reboot/shutdown (ie. REISUB,REISUO); if you don't remember the commands using a phone to search "*magic sysrq*" usually finds the wikipedia page which is as good as any as it's Linux specific, not Ubuntu related.  After an unclean shutdown, I'd recommend booting *live* media & `fsck` your partitions & look for issues using *live* media. You haven't said if you made any changes last session

Comment: There was no change with the last session

Comment: The power-off using a power-off (unclean shutdown) is a *change* thus my prior comment; ie. boot *live* media and check for damage done. Using a safe power off method (login to terminal, or if you're in a hurry using SysRq commands direct to kernel is still faster than the dangerous power-off button that risks damage to file-system itself)